# My VB form design has gone blank after deleting an image in my resources

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I was in my project resources, removing some jpeg images that I thought weren't of any use. After i deleted one, my form design came up with an error which I arrogantly clicked ignore and continue, I can't recall what it actually said but I remember it mentioning an error in the XAML code on a certain line. After, my form had gone completely blank. All the buttons and such which did exist on the design which are referred to in the vb code still exist and don't bring any errors when ran, it just makes an empty form.

I'm far from experienced with using VB and visual studio, I'm hoping I'm being stupid and the solution takes just a few clicks,

Comment: Open up the Form's designer's code (double click on, e.g.,  `Form1.vb -> Form1 -> InitializeComponent()` method), look for Images assigned from the Project's Reources: if will be something like `Global.YourProjectName.My.Resources.Resources.TheImageName`, remove all these and rebuild the Solution. Make a copy of the designer's file (e.g., Form1.Designer.vb) beforehand. Depending on the VS version, the error may persist (because of the `.resx` file). Closing VS and then rebuilding the Solution may help.

Comment: Hi jimi this is what the initialise sub looks like

Comment: That method, in a VB.Net project, is usually in the Form.Designer file (unless you have created a `Sub New()` method in the Form's file). So, if you double-click it, it will open that file. Just for this reason; of course you can open it in different ways. Once the file is opened, look for the images coming from the Project's Resources.

Comment: Are you using source control (e.g. Git)? If so, you can review the history of the commit just prior to your accidental deletion and restore only that code.